# Add Polymer elements conditionally

Tags: javascript, polymer

i want to add polymer elements on certain conditions. The condition must be requested from a server asynchronously

```
request().done(function(msg){//msg is the answer from the server});
```

I've found the dom-if in the Polymer documentation. If I have understood correctly, i have to pass a property or computed property to the if condition

```
<template is="dom-if" if="{{...}}></template>
```

I have no idea how to combine the asynchronus method call with the dom-if

```
<template is="dom-if" if="{{request().done(...)}}></template>
```

Edited:

I want to use the dom-if multiple times on different pages. So i implemented it as a new behavior with an conditional function

```
showElement(id: String)

<template is="dom-if" if="{{showElement(foo)}}"></template>
```

The problem is, that server request is asynchronous, so i can't return the answer in the behavior:

```
showElement: function(id) {
  request(id).done(function(anwser) {
    return answer;   
  }
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance

Best Regards,
Christian

Comment: what type of condition can you get from server? what is the format? What you are trying to do is a little bit complicated. And without more informations it is almost impossible to answer

Comment: I pass an ID as string to the method call. The server decides by the ID whether the element is to be shown or not an returns a boolean.

server.request("element-id").done(function(anser){showElement = answer});

Answer (score 2):

If the method handling your server response is in a context aware of the element containing your dom-if, you can set a property binded to your dom-if in it.

You declare a property in your element containing the dom-if, and set it to false by default.

```
//properties declaration...
showElement : {
    type:Boolean,
    value: false
}
//others properties and end of properties declaration...
```

You declare your dom-if to be binded on this property

```
<template is="dom-if" if="{{showElement}}">...</template>
```

And in your method handling the server response, something like that.

```
if(condition is met){
    this.showElement = true;
}
```

The last part suppose the context of your handling function is the one of your element containing the property and the dom-if.

If it isn't the case, I'll need more details on how the request is fired and handled to extend this response and explain how to retrieve it.

Comment: Ok, from what I understand on your additions, your request is run one time, and return a complexe object with the condition, but for many different items with id, and each item should have a dom-if. If your list of id is already know, you can use the same idea, but instead of setting a simple boolean property, set an object with a property set to false for each id, and change it when you get your response. And your dom-if becomes `<template is="dom-if" if="{{showElement.id1}}">...</template>` etc...

Answer (score 0):

If your server returns boolean, then it is simple. You can simply just do:

`<template is="dom-if" if="{{foo}}"></template>`

Which means, whenever you get response from server, you have to set it to `foo` property: `this.set("foo", response...)`. This is the first step. You didn't mentioned when you want to fire request to server or how often. Anyway, you can do it, for example, when screen is loaded or whatever. Async will not be a problem here then.

Using behavior is good. But instead of `return` it should only set value to property

Summary: when the page is loaded (or input is changes, or user presses button ...), you call request on server -> wait for response -> when response comes, set it to (for example) `foo` property -> and that's it.

And last thing, default value of `foo` should be propably `false`.

Almost the same mentioned Arfost above. And he is right, so where is the problem

**EDIT**

According to your comment, you got always 1 ID which is bounded to 1 response from server based on value of ID. So for example, if ID is 5 then some other property is `true` and this property changes on Id's value.

So, without any additional code, you could propably do it something like:

```
showElement: function(id, property, value) {
  if(value == undefined) {
    request(id).done(function(answer) {
      this.set(property, answer); 
    }
  }
}
```

and binding will be like:

```
<template is="dom-if" if="{{showElement(someID, 'foo1', foo1)}}"></template>
```

assuming property `foo1` doesn't exists. You mustn't declare it. This is most important, because of conditional `if(value == undefined)` otherwise it won't be ever called.

just to explain `showElement(someID, 'foo1', foo1)`:
`'foo1'` (second parameter) is representing name of property where should be stored response from server.
`foo1` (third parameter) is here, because of binding. Thanks to this, `dom-if` will get noticed, whenever property `foo1` changes.

I didn't tested it, but i think it might work.

Comment: The request must only be sent once on creation time. But the problem is that i have more than one dom-if elements  `<template is="dom-if" if="{{foo-1}}"></template>`
The next problem is that i need association between the dom-if and the id for the server request. But when i use a method-call in the if condition
`<template is="dom-if" if="{{showElement(id-1)}}"></template>` i can't use a boolean value like suggested

Comment: thank you for your answer, Kuba. But in this case, i have to add additionally code (e.g. to the ready-lifecycle method). is there a way to solve the problem only with the dom-if tag?

Comment: @Meisenmann  Of course, there is a solution, but it would take more lines of code and it would be much more complicated than it is now. The problem is, that it would get into infinite cycle and so on.. blablabla.. just complicated things. Answer I provided is propably (at least for now) best.  Well, i got one idea. If you really need it so much much much much, tell me. But really, above code is great enough

Comment: It is necessary to provide an "api" that is as simple as possible. users (=collegues) of the "api" don't want to add different parts of code just to hide something. if you have a idea, i would be greatful if you coult give me (just a few) points. Thanks in advance

Comment: @Meisenmann hope i made my last edit. If this won't work then i am out of ideas

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Properties must be explicitely defined for your suggestion. The IDs are very long and containing dots as well. But I solved the problem with a new polymer element that contains the dom-if, handles the server request and assosciates it with its own property